# Python on Windows not working on Raspbery Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have developed the code on my Windows machine but when I transfer it the my Raspberry Pi get the directory or file not found errors.

windows code extract is

```
#Refresh the data by calling NodeJS API
subprocess.call(['node', r'C:\Users\david\GrowattAPI\write.js'], shell=True)
```

I have the following on the Raspberry Pi

```
#Refresh the data by calling NodeJS API
subprocess.call(['node', '/home/pi/Documents/write.js'], shell=True)
```

The node call does not work. If I do it manually it works. e.g. node write.js

Any ideas?

Thanks

UPDATE - SOLVED

The syntax of the subprocess.call when using the pi is required to be

```
subprocess.call(['node /home/pi/Documents/write.js'], shell=True)
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Try with absolute paths instead of relative paths

Comment: permission issue? you could try `sudo chmod 777 write.js`

Comment: Have you created a distribution and installed it on the raspberry PI or did you just copy the python script?

Comment: NirO I have just copied it. Run with python3 update.py